# How to modify the DataLabel fill (using a solid fill color)?

Tags: python-3.6, python-pptx

I'm trying to edit the data labels for a chart I'm writing on the slide.  I can access the text of the datalabel using the methods available but as of yet the datalabel.fill is not existent.  Any workarounds welcome if this is not planned on being added to the library in the future.

I've already gone through the source code in the github (https://github.com/scanny/python-pptx) but the datalabel class only has the font, has_text_frame, position, text_frame, _dLbl, _get_or_add_dLbl, _get_or_add_rich, _get_or_add_tx_rich, _get_or_add_txPr, and _remove_tx_rich methods.  No fill or line fill methods is available.

The script I'm running does something similar for cells in a table:

```
    cell.fill.solid()
    cell.fill.fore_color.rgb = color_list[((col>0)*1)][i%2]
```

I'm looking at replicating the functionality on datalabels for chart series, with code that looks like this:

```
    label.fill.solid()
    label.fill.rgb = RGBColor(0x9B,0xBB,0x59)
    label.fill.alpha = Alpha(.2)
    label.line.fill.solid()
    label.line.rgb = RGBColor(0xF0,0xF0,0x00)
```

The expected output xml should put the following for data labels:

```
    <c:spPr>
     <a:solidFill>
      <a:srgbClr val="9BBB59">
       <a:alpha val="80000"/>
      </a:srgbClr>
     </a:solidFill>
     <a:ln>
      <a:solidFill>
       <a:schemeClr val="F0F000"/>
      </a:solidFill>
     </a:ln>
    </c:spPr>
```

Actual output is non-existent as there is no method to do this directly.

Answer (score 0):

This feature is not yet implemented, but if it *was* implemented it would be a `.format` property on the `DataLabel` object.

Typically users will work around an API gap like this by adding what we typically call a "workaround function" to the client code that manipulates the underlying XML directly, in this case, to add an `<c:spPr>` subtree in the right place.

`python-pptx` can generally get you close as far as a parent element is concerned. In this case, it can get you to the `<c:dLbl>` element like this:

```
data_label = chart.series[0].points[0].data_label
dLbl = data_label._dLbl
print(dLbl.xml)
```

The leading underscore in `._dLbl` is your hint that you're getting into internals and if things don't go well it's something you're doing wrong, not an issue to be reported.

The `dLbl` object is an `lxml.etree._Element` object and can be manipulated with that API. If you have a search on "python-pptx workaround function" you'll find some examples for how to create new elements and put them where you want them.

The `.xml` property available on any `python-pptx` XML element object is handy for inspecting the results along the way. `opc-diag` can also be handy for inspecting PPTX files generated by PowerPoint or `python-pptx` for analysis or diagnostic purposes.

Comment: When will this feature be implemented?Thanks for all the great work.